# How can I merge/collapse multiple frames into one single frame in Spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, frames

Sometimes I have multiple open frames (not only windows) in Spacemacs, and would like to collapse all frames into one single frame. That's easier to keep track on open buffers.

However, I cant' find a way to collapse all frames into one. I'm aware that I can kill open frames, but that's not what I want.

1. Question:

How can I collapse all open frames into one single frame in Spacemacs (or Emacs)?

---

*EDIT*: To clarify, what I want, please consider the following images.

**What I have**:

[image]

Multiple Windows appear in multiple frames.

**What I WANT**:

[image]

I would like to collect all windows within *one* frame. That is, whereas before the $n$ windows were spread across $k$ frames, now I want to have the $n$ windows within one frame.

Of course, I could delete all other frames, and then reopen the windows in my main, single, remaining frame. But I do not reopen all the windows again. Rather, I'm looking for a key binding that changes from "what I have" to "what I want"

---

(2nd question deleted as asked by Editor)

Comment: Please do not [x-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/232422): https://stackoverflow.com/q/58833125/2708138

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "collapse" and how that's different from what `delete-other-frames` (bound to `C-x 5 1` by default) does.

Comment: @Stefan The OP does not mention `delete-other-frames` in his question and `delete-other-frames` is not in the file-menu by default. So I assume that the OP just not knew about `delete-other-frames` and I informed him for that reason in my answer about it.

Comment: The question is unclear, and so risks being deleted. Please specify what you mean by "collapsing" multiple frames into one frame.

Comment: Also, regarding the last pargraph: plase make it a separate question.  @Tobias indeed it's not clear whether he knows about `delete-other-frames` (his mention of "I can kill other frames" suggests that maybe he does), that's part of the problem.

Comment: @Stefan: I've now taken out the 2nd question.

Comment: @Stefan, @Tobias, @Drew, Thanks for your suggestions. I know about `delete-other-frames`, but I do not want to delete. Rather, I'd like to "merge" the $k$ frames with $n$ windows into 1 frame with the $k$ windows. Please see the screenshots above.

Comment: I deleted my answer to avoid the impression of an appearently answered question in the question list. Nevertheless, I think that `delete-other-frames` is the basic building block for a solution of your problem. There are still open questions. What is if the other frames have multiple windows? There is great danger that the single remaining frame becomes very cluttered up.

Comment: Sebastian Sauer: If you want to give it a whirl, I expect a basic implementation can be put together using the following functions: `frame-list`, `selected-frame`, `walk-windows`, `window-buffer`, `split-window-below` (or perhaps `split-root-window-below` in Emacs 29+), `set-window-buffer`, `delete-frame`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newish `tab-bar-mode` might help here.

If the desire is to consolidate the window or even multiple windows that may be open in a second frame into the first frame, but with’s n-number of window splits, @Tobias ‘s comment above about the dangers of the frame being too cluttered are valid, and you’d need some separate logic to determine how to lay the windows out.

Using the tab-bar (available from Emacs 27 on) seems simpler and helps here as it retains the window layouts of the multiple frames, but allows you to bring them together into just one frame. Each tab in tab-bar-mode is a frame-like object and can have multiple windows in it.

If you:

- enable tab-bar with `M-x tab-bar-mode` turning on tabs in all the frames.
- switch to the “other” frame (the one you no longer want) `C-x 5 o` if you weren’t there already
- the windows in the second frame should now be part of a tab and can be moved to the first frame with `M-x tab-bar-move-tab-to-frame`

If you have more than two frames, it may ask which you want to move the tab to, but if you only had two frames, as in the OP question, the first is automatically chosen as the destination and the second frame will be gone.

The remaining frame will have two tabs in the tab-bar, one containing its original windows and the other containing the windows from the former frame.